# Stop `submit` button blowing up rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my form for uploading a new profile image:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :avatar do |f| %>
        <%= f.file_field :file_name %>
        <%= f.submit 'Upload new Profile Image' %>
    <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Works perfectly. However, when someone presses the submit button before selecting the image, my controller gives me this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing
```

On production, it has the effect of completely seizing up the application. So how should I get around this?

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_user, only: [:create]


  def create
    @user.create_avatar(file_name: image_params[:avatar][:file_name])

    redirect_to @user, success: 'Profile image created!'
  end


  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def image_params
    params.require(:user).permit(avatar: [:file_name])
  end
end
```

Comment: what happens if you put the f.submit... outside the fields_for block? also, copy your controller's code

Comment: `ActionController::ParameterMissing in ImagesController#create
param not found: user`

Comment: Just saying, even when I move it outside the `fields_for`, it works perfectly. It just when the submit is hit without a file selected.

Comment: @user3067865 Can you share the server log for when you submit the form without uploading an image?

Answer (score 1):

You have this

```
def image_params
  params.require(:user).permit(avatar: [:file_name])
end
```

so it's requiring a :user param as "params[:user]", but it's nil because, when you have nothing selected, the form doesn't even send the param

You should remove that "require(:user)" and handle the two posible situations where the param is/isn't present doing different things (maybe: if present, upload, if not present just redirect back and display an error).